# Java 8 reduce method calls depending on a value

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

How to optimize method that returns the first non empty value returned of the `checkN()` methods and prevent the rest method calls and `isEmpty()` calls:

```
private String validate() {
    String message = check1();

    if (message.isEmpty()) {
        message = check2();
    }

    if (message.isEmpty()) {
        message = check3();
    }

    // total 5+ checks been called

    return message;
}
```

#1 I thought of using stream filter and return first that has value, but it requires to call each check:

```
return Stream.of(check1(), check2(), check3(), ...).filter(message -> !message.isEmpty()).findFirst().orElse("");
```

SOLVED

as M A suggested, finalized solution for me was:

```
public static String method(Some a, Other b) {
        return Stream.<Supplier<String>>of(
                // for the methods without params
                myClass::check1,
                // for the methods with params
                () -> check2(a),
                () -> check3(a, b))
        .map(Supplier::get)
        .filter(StringUtils::isNotBlank)
        .findFirst().orElse("");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of constructing a Stream of Strings, you can do a Stream of `Supplier<String>`, which would defer the invocation of the method until the filter needs to be checked in the stream pipeline:

```
return Stream.<Supplier<String>>of(this::check1, this::check2, this::check3, ...)
            .filter(check -> !check.get().isEmpty())
            .findFirst()
            .map(Supplier::get)
            .orElse("");
```

A better variant is to do the mapping from `Supplier` to the result `String` before the filter (the advantage is that this won't call the method with the non-empty result twice):

```
return Stream.<Supplier<String>>of(this::check1, this::check2, this::check3, ...)
            .map(Supplier::get)
            .filter(message -> !message.isEmpty())
            .findFirst()
            .orElse("");
```

Comment: How would you achieve this when the ```check``` methods are static and for each check call the parameters differs?

Comment: @lpkej Read about [method references](https://dev.java/learn/writing-lambda-expressions-as-method-references/) for how to reference static methods. But you can also still use a lambda expression, for example: `Stream.<Supplier<String>>of(() -> check1("a", "b"), () -> check2("a"), MyClass::check3, ...)` (assuming `check1` takes two parameters `"a"` and `"b"`, and `check2` takes one parameter.

Comment: Also, ```org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils::isNotBlank``` is more convenient to use instead of ```message -> !message.isEmpty()```

Comment: The second version is much cleaner, really enjoyed it. I think since it's not specified whether the result returned by `check()` is consistent and whether this call is costful or not, it better to invoke `get()` only once.

Comment: @lpkej as far as I know, `isNotBlank` does not the same as testing for “not `isEmpty()`” but that’s the problem with external libraries. You have to consult their documentation to find out. Even if it did the same, it’s questionable to add a dependency to an external library just for a tiny bit of source code convenience. It seems, people did not learn anything from the log4j disaster. By the way, since JDK 11 you can use `Predicate.not(String::isEmpty)` if using a method reference means that much to you. You can also use `Predicate.not(String::isBlank)` if you really want test for “blank”.

Answer (score 1):

You said you thought of stream filter first but a stream is not really required in this case.

- creating a list of suppliers is the clearly the right approach
- but you need to reverse the test condition and return if true (i.e. the message is not empty).
- just continue to call the methods until the test succeeds and returns the message.

```
List<Supplier<String>> checkList = List.of(this::check1,
        this::check2, this::check3, this::check4, this::check5);

    
private String validate() {
    String message;
    for (Supplier<String> nextCheck : checkList) {
        if (!(message = nextCheck.get()).isEmpty()) {
            return message;
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Note that you could have achieved the same optimization using your initial approach but changing the condition.

```
public String validiate() {
    String message;
    if (!(message = check1()).isEmpty()) {
        return message;
    }
    if (!(message = check2()).isEmpty()) {
        return message;
    }
    if (!(message = check3()).isEmpty()) {
        return message;
    }
    
    // other message checks
    
    return "";
}
```